# How to do a data search on remote pc's

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a script:

```
get-childitem c:\users -include *.mov,*.avi,*.asf,*.flv,*.swf,*.mpg,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.wav,*.jpg,*.tif,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp 
-recurse > collection.txt
```

This works great when collecting on a local computer.  However, I need to run the same thing on several computers at once. So I tried this in a BAT file:

```
PSexec @list.txt -u UserID -p Password PowerShell get-childitem c:\users -include *.mov,*.avi,*.asf,*.flv,*.swf,*.mpg,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.wav,*.jpg,*.tif,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp 
-recurse > collection.txt 2>&1 pause
```

This worked on some remote PC's, but I ran into a couple of problems:

1) The collection.txt file contains all the information with no identification of which piece goes with which computer.

2) When running on a single computer, sometimes, it looks like it is running, but never finishes and/or never reports that it has completed or writes to the file.

Is there another way to collect the same data for all users that have logged into the computer? Or, am I just not doing it right

Comment: Problem 1 and 2 are when I run it on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to use PSRemoting rather than PSExec.

```
$list = "RemoteComputer1","RemoteComputer2"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $list -ScriptBlock {get-childitem c:\users -include *.mov,*.avi,*.asf,*.flv,*.swf,*.mpg,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.wav,*.jpg,*.tif,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp -recurse} | Out-File .\collection.txt
```

If you need to use PSExec and a BAT file:

```
PSexec @list.txt -u UserID -p Password PowerShell -command $env:computername; get-childitem c:\users -include *.mov,*.avi,*.asf,*.flv,*.swf,*.mpg,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.wav,*.jpg,*.tif,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp -recurse 2>&1 > collection.txt
```